# angular 6 router.redirect doesnt call onInit()

Tags: angular

I have problem with navigation.
My goal was:

After login, enable some menu items, hide other menu items, redirect to some page

my appComponent.ts code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const identity = ApiQueryService.GetIdentity();
    if (identity === null || identity.length < 1) {
      this.logged = false;
    } else {
      this.logged = true;
    }
  }
```

my appComponent.html code:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!logged">
  <nav>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" [routerLink]="['/register']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Register</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" [routerLink]="['/login']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Login</a>
  </nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-container>


<ng-container *ngIf="logged">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" [routerLink]="['/myProfile']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">My profile</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" [routerLink]="['/friends']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Friends</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" [routerLink]="['/messages']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Messages</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" [routerLink]="['/find']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Find users</a>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-2 dual-collapse2">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" (click)="logout()">Wyloguj</a>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" style="width:70%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

</ng-container>
```

as you can see i have variable logged in appComponent.ts
if someone is logged i dont want to show login/register menu

so, the next component is login component:

```
onSubmit(loginFormRef: NgForm) {
      this.usersService.LoginUser(this.login, this.password).subscribe(result => {
      this.logged = true;

      loginFormRef.resetForm();
      this.router.navigate(['/myProfile']);
    }, (error) => {
      ApiQueryService.ClearLoginInfos();
      this.loginFailed = true;
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

and in my profile, like on every other component where you have to be logged in:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.identity = ApiQueryService.GetIdentity();
    if (this.identity.length < 1) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    this.fillUserDetailsDictionary();


  }
```

problem is that after login, it doesnt break on appCopomonent. ngOnInit() neither myProfile.ngOnInit()
both are marked as impelement ngOnInit

**if i will hit [enter] keyboard on web browser it works ok ;)**

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz code?

Comment: you wouldn't test it anyway because it is calling api every query

Comment: Then you must explain in that way that anyone can understand by reading itself only! Like Expected, Current and your try!

Comment: the question is bolded

Comment: If you create a stackblitz you don't need to provide a API. Your `usersService.LoginUser()` function can simply return `true` or what ever you would expect the API to return.